# Is there a way to prolong the timeout period when sharing my files to a windows pc?

Tags: 16.04, windows, sharing

A bit broad, but is there a way to prolong the timeout period when sharing files to a windows pc from an ubuntu pc, samba keeps quitting on me after every 3 minutes tops.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several timeouts that can be set within Samba and they depend on how the connection is being made (CUPS, LDAP etc.). For each type of timeout there is a directive that you can alter that can be found in `/etc/smb.conf`. For information on each, please see the documentation [here](https://www.samba.org/samba/docs/man/manpages/smb.conf.5.html).

Hint: `ctrl+F timeout`